# JQuery scroll to next non sibling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a highlighted search that adds class .highlight to a keyword that I typed, then I tried to write piece of code that would scroll through all of elements that have class .highlight. Code kind of works because it finds all elements with .highlight but scrolls only to the first one.

This is my function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#next").click(function () {
            var next = $(this).parent().nextAll().find(".highlight");
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: next.ofsset().top}, 500);

    });
});
```

Comment: I think '$(this)' always indicates the element named with 'next' whenever click event triggers. That's why it scrolls to the first highlighted text.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it. Basically keep track of the current item and use that base to find the next item:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var current = "";
    $("#next").click(function () {
       if (current == "") {
         current = $(".highlight");
       }
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: current.offset().top}, 500);
        current = current.nextAll(".highlight");
        //If this is the last item you can reset or disable the click functionality
        if (current.length == 0) {
          $( "#next" ).prop( "disabled", true );//disable button
          // -OR-
          current = $(".highlight"); //reset button

        }
    });
});
```

This will also allow you to reset current if you want to start over from the top.

Alternatively you could use classes to keep track of the current item. This has the benefit of making it easy to restart as well as allowing you to add some sort of formatting to the current item:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#next").click(function () {

       var currentHighlight;
       if ($(".current-highlight").length == 0) {
         currentHighlight = $(".highlight").first().addClass("current-highlight");
       }
       else {
          currentHighlight = $(".current-highlight").nextAll(".highlight");
          //Either exit or restart on the last item
          if (currentHighlight.length == 0 ) {
            $( "#next" ).prop( "disabled", true );//disable button
            // -OR-
            currentHighlight = $(".highlight"); //reset button
          }
          $(".current-highlight").removeClass("current-highlight");
          currentHighlight.addClass("current-highlight");
       }

        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: currentHighlight.offset().top}, 500);

    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this at first but it didn't work because I add .highlight with js after I type it in a searchbox.

Comment: ok I see. What if you initialize current to empty and then populate it on first run. I have updated my answer. Let me know if that could work

Comment: Yes that works now but it only goes to the first element then it catches an error: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)

Comment: Which method did you use. #1 or #2?

Comment: I used the second method

Comment: Sorry I meant the first one I didn't see the second one Im sorry

Comment: aaahhh!! I forgot to add error checking for the last item. It's late here :( I just updated the answer. Let me know if that works for you

Comment: The first one now does not return an error but it just goes to the first element, I think it does that because it always declares var current = "" but i doubt that.

Comment: Strange that it does not work for you. Do you have enough content on your page to make the page scrollable? Here is a quick fiddle showing the code working: https://jsfiddle.net/g4yhdbn8/38/

Comment: Yes I have more than enough content and it scrolls to the first element with highlight. Do you think it can be a problem because they are not siblings and are table elements.

Comment: As long as you are using the highlight class it should not matter what the element is. Can you create a quick fiddle showing your code in action or update your answer with some html?

Comment: Yes I can, just a moment

Comment: Here you have it. It kindof works like it's supose to. https://jsfiddle.net/Stu076/t4b9xmfc/#&togetherjs=Didmg2MqtJ

Comment: ok I see. You are going to have to reset things on every search. I would recommend using method #2 and then whenever you get a new search call  $(".current-highlight").removeClass("current-highlight"); Also if you are going to disable the next button when you get to the last highlight item then re-enable it on every search as well